# Who are the red masked guards in the rathtar scene of TFA

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

Near the beginning of the rathtar scene in *The Force Awakens*, there are several guards or companions in the background. They never say anything that I can recall.  Do we know who/what these are?

[image: scene]

Comment: "Do we know who/what these are?" Awesome-looking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the foot soldiers of the Guavian Death Gang based on the canon source [Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/guavian-death-gang).

> Known for its distinctive red-armored foot soldiers, the Guavian Death Gang is a criminal organization driven out of the Core Worlds by unrest in the galactic underworld. Guavian Death Gang soldiers undergo cybernetic augmentation, with a mechanical reservoir and pump injecting chemicals into their bloodstreams to enhance speed and aggression. They are silent in battle, communicating via high-frequency datastreams. Han Solo ran afoul of the Guavians for failing to repay their 50,000-credit loan.

Answer (score 7):

According to the film's Visual [Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary), these individuals are "**Security Soldiers**", loyal to the Guavian Death Gang.

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, the licensed toy refers to them as "**Guavian Enforcers**"

[image]